# ArcMap tool dialog says relative paths are incorrect

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters, input

I have ArcMap 10.7.1 and I have created a Python script tool and tool dialog to run on it.

I want to set a default value for one of my inputs on the tool dialog and have it be a relative path to a file within the folder I intend on sharing with others. However, when I input in the relative path onto the tool dialog's default (and even if I just input in the relative path straight away) the tool dialog says the file path is invalid.

[image: input is invalid]

[image: My file directory]

In the images above, I'm running the script in the toolbox and using the Item.shp as an input. However, it seems as though my relative path `..\Data\Inputs\Item.shp` is not accepted.

I was wondering if there's a correct way to enter in the relative paths, or if it is something else in the code that I am missing.

How would I need to type the relative path into the GUI in order for it to be accepted?

Note that when I use the absolute path for the shapefile it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Relative paths may not be supported for this application.  There is a note about a third of the way down the [Absolute, relative, UNC, and URL paths](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm) page, that says "You cannot type relative paths (using the dot and double-dot notation) in any ArcGIS application."

[image: screenshot]

[@Hornbydd has suggested in the comments](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417955/arcmap-gui-says-relative-paths-are-incorrect#comment680514_417955) that if the default dataset is always called *Item.shp* and located in the same sub-folder, your script could build the path to it.

If that's the case, you could change your ***Input shapefile*** parameter to be **optional** and then have your script test for a null value, e.g.

```
inputData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if inputData is None:
    inputData = r"<path to installed location>\Deliverables\Data\Input\Item.shp"
```

If you need to programmatically find the execution folder for the script when the toolbox has been installed by a user, [How do you properly determine the current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory) (from Stack Overflow) will help.  You will then be able to work back from the script location to define the path to your default shapefile.